# EXTJS 4 - How to skip individual cells when using tab key through a grid but keep tab press start edit next editable cell?

Tags: extjs, grid, extjs4, tablecelleditor

I have a grid, with cell editing and row selection model. I use tab to go to next cell and start to edit it, but there are cells which I need to skip editing, but when peressing a tab need to go to next editable cell.

If I just "return false" from "beforeedit" event, it cancels the whole editing process so I need to use the mouse again, thats wrong.

How can I skipp cells but keep the tabbing working?

```
        plugins: [
            Ext.create('Ext.grid.plugin.CellEditing', {
                clicksToEdit: 1,
                listeners: {
                    beforeedit: {
                        fn: me.onCellEditingBeforeEdit,
                        scope: me
                    }
                }
            })
        ]
```

here is the before edit function:

```
onCellEditingBeforeEdit: function(editor, e, eOpts) {

    var isEditable=this.isCellEditabe(editor, e); // return false if the cell is not editable

    if (!isEditable)
    {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: where is your code? You should put in here then we can think of it!

Comment: I don't think it is necessary for this. But I edited the original post.

Comment: see my answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16016073/how-to-skip-over-particular-cells-when-tabbing-through-an-ext-grid/37680711#37680711

Answer (score 0):

I found somewhere in a .net forum the solution:

```
Ext.selection.RowModel.override({
        onEditorTab: function(editingPlugin, e) {
           var me = this,
            view = me.views[0],
            record = editingPlugin.getActiveRecord(),
            header = editingPlugin.getActiveColumn(),
            position = view.getPosition(record, header),
            direction = e.shiftKey ? 'left' : 'right',
            columnHeader;

        // We want to continue looping while:
        // 1) We have a valid position
        // 2) There is no editor at that position
        // 3) There is an editor, but editing has been cancelled (veto event)

        do {
            position  = view.walkCells(position, direction, e, me.preventWrap);
            columnHeader = view.headerCt.items.getAt(position.column);
        } while (position && (!columnHeader.getEditor(record) || !editingPlugin.startEditByPosition(position)));
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

use this as config in your current grid:

```
var grid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    ...
    selModel: Ext.create('selection.cellmodel', {
        onEditorTab: function(editingPlugin, e) {
            var me = this,
                direction = e.shiftKey ? 'left' : 'right',
                position  = me.move(direction, e);

            if (position) {
                while(!editingPlugin.startEdit(position.row, position.column)){
                    position = me.move(direction, e);

                    // go to first editable cell
                    if(!position) editingPlugin.startEdit(0, 1); // TODO: make this dynamic
                }
                me.wasEditing = false;

            } else {
                // go to first editable cell
                if (editingPlugin.startEdit(0, 1)) { // TODO: make this dynamic
                    me.wasEditing = false;
                }
            }
        },
    }),
    //selType: 'cellmodel', // remove selType
    ...
})
```